# Connecting multiple 1inch lcd displays to only one MCU

Tags: microcontroller, lcd, display

i'd need to connect multiple very small (1inch if not slightly more) square lcd displays to only one controller unit.

I searched for it but being not an electrical engineer it seems i lack some keywords or knowledge in the matter.

What i found is that websites as alibaba or similar ones are selling those kind of displays but each one needs its own controller.

I'll be more specific:
- i don't need extended rendering, so each display will show the same content;
- the mcu should be as small as one of those displays, so 1inch;
- an acceptable resolution, readable;
- a way to program that controller (simple tasks). 
- no touch screen either. 
Any kind of help would be very appreciated, from where should i start? Is there some website or whatever who could custom build it (given the tiny size)?
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, we're your personal googlers.

Comment: Datasheet of the display please.

Comment: Here is it, https://files.fm/u/vgqt8yym, something the likes of this one. Just varying in size, thank you again.

Comment: How many screens? Why do they need to be so small? Do you need touchscreen input?

Comment: No touchscreen input, and quantity let's say about 4 screens. Thanks for your time.

Comment: that display you linked is not a "my first display" kind of display you probably want something with a spi or i2c interface.  but saying that, the bottom line is there are displays without controllers but less likely to find those, most will have a controller and that is what you are talking to with your mcu, so you simply look up the data sheet for that controller and find the protocol, rules, etc.  there are good sized ones like that with spi or uart interfaces allowing a small/simple mcu to be in charge.  do you need color or is mono okay?  how many pixels? etc.

Comment: if you want multiple and you need 10-20 pins per think about just how big of a part is required.  if you need to store all the pixels times the number of bits per pixel in the device (not always required, but lazy folks do this as a habit) times number of displays, how big of a frame buffer do you need.  Does the display need constant refresh or does it or its controller have storage for the data such that you dont necessarily need a full framebuffer in the mcu?  maybe you are displaying text and you only need the text in the mcu and convert to pixels on the way out.

Comment: Hey old_timer, at best i would like to render small and really simple images so colors even with really small res would be perfect.

Comment: I didnt know about displays that don't need mcu, ill look into it, for answering some of your questions: i could display only text for sure, don't have to store pixels, no constant refresh either. Mono color only if really is impossible with colors. Thank you for the really useful answers!

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I haven't worked with TFT displays, so I don't know what they are supposed to do. However, I did work with the [Hitachi HD44780](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitachi_HD44780_LCD_controller) LCD controllers we all know and use for adding text output to Arduino projects. Therefore, I will assume that these TFTs act at least in some way that's close to these. **However,** you do need to test and see whether after the screen update the display pulls any of the data pins to a different state. If it does, then that which is described below may fail explosively as each display tries to pull the data pins to a different state.

If every screen has to show the same image, then connecting several together is as simple as linking together all the data pins and the trigger pins. Since every display will be receiving the same data, they will all update simultaneously.

But making it so that each display does its own thing is not that difficult either: you common all the data pins and separate the trigger pins. *The 8-Bit Guy* has a [video](https://youtu.be/vV8FbwobrKY?t=11m34s) that discusses the LCD character displays based on the HD44780 mentioned above, and that video is where I got the idea from. Basically, the point is that the display should check the data pins only when triggered by the trigger pins; thus, it should ignore what's on the data lines when we're not triggering it. Note that, unless you do something clever in the software, the top speed at which you can drive the displays is decreased for every new one you add: that is to say, with two displays, the speed is halved, with three, the speed is one-third of the max, and so on.

But really, *really*, if your project needs the four displays that badly (and for the record, I haven't had a project that needed more than one yet), then you're better off slapping a separate micro on the back of each display, and some form of centralized control over them (as in, linking them all up to a [Raspberry Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) with [I2C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) or something). A quick read through the datasheet suggests that you need 10 pins to drive this thing; if so, to equip the displays with their own dedicated micros, you would want a bag of surface-mount [ATmega 328s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATmega328) and a glue gun.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed informations, i'll start working on it using those infos,  and will for sure update you all soon with each and every detail.

Comment: @LucaDalessandro You're welcome. For future reference, most of the displays you'll find on the market are very much simpler to use than the one to which you linked, precisely because they have the controller on board. For instance, [this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2088) display from Adafruit uses the ST7735R TFT driver, and you tell it what to display using a library they've made for you, and communication is done via 4-wire SPI. Then the number that you can drive from one micro will depend on the number of SPI extensions on-chip. (You could add some more with bit-banging, though.)